# Upgrading dataflow sdk to 2.X.X from 1.9.X gives build errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I upgraded dataflow sdk package version and started getting below error:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for
>   com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$FileBasedWriteOperation.
>   Fix the build path then try building this project(edited)

I also tried  Maven -> Update Project item, check the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases", that did not help.
If I downgrade back to older version 1.9.0 error goes away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized, to upgrade to 2.X there are a lot more breaking changes, [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2)

Comment: Correct: 2.0 is the first API-stable release. There will be no breaking changes between 2.x and 2.y releases, except for APIs explicitly marked @Experimental (but we avoid breaking those too).